# How to get a particular table cell text with row column values in Capybara without looping?

Tags: ruby, capybara, tablecell

How can get the text in a cell at position `(row_no , col_no)` of a table in Capybara?
In `Watir` it was easy to fetch a table element and do `table_element[2][3]`.

**How can this be done in Capybara?**

Comment: have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526036/how-to-get-a-html-table-row-with-capybara

Comment: Yes I have taken a look,its perfect for looping thru entire table. But what I want is exact cell data when row and column no are given. I would try avoiding traversing thru all rows and column , if possible!!The below answer by @wicz might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capybara also supports [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) for querying:

```
page.has_selector?(:xpath, '//table/tr[2]/td[3]')
```

There is this nice [cheat sheet](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/) in case you want deepen your knowledge on how to traverse documents with XPath.

HTH.

Comment: great, this will definitely work in Capybara. I'm just trying it out in a little different manner. And the cheatsheet is amazing!!

Comment: if I have the row and col no i can probabaly create a xpath string and make it general too:
`def get_cell_text(row,col)
   xpath_string = "//table/tr[#{row}]/td[#{col}]"
   page.has_selector?(:xpath, xpath_string)
end`

But Yes will  this work only assuming the table built follows the usual table row column ideology(without the tbody,tfooter etc)?

Comment: For these cases you can use `//table//tr/td`. See, the operator `/` means _direct_ child. The double-slash `//` means descendants, thus ignoring intermediate hierarchy. Check this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Examples).